# How to limit Chrome desktop shortcut so that it cannot be opened more than once

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-customization, application-launch

I have a Chrome desktop shortcut and it work fine, but some user open this shortcut more than once.

How can i prevent from this behaviour ? What i would is that if the users click more than once over my shortcut, then the just opened windows is maximized again.

Comment: You want to restrict users from opening a web browser more than once at a time? Maybe you should write a script that uses an `if` condition rather than an application shortcut

Comment: Contribute to **[Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)** and program it to be mono-instance, install the new version, profit.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the site is used by a company that has strinct policy, so i have no choiche i need to use chrome.

Comment: @Raystafarian the user can open browser more than once, but can not open my page twice.
Users are not so troubles maker to intentionally open a new browser page if we explicitly have told them not to do so.
But sometimes they make mistake and click more than twice over shortcut.
I would prevent this kind of mistake and a little batch script is acceptable, did you know what i need to test in my IF clause ?

Comment: @skary Chromium is Chrome...

Comment: If you are trying to prevent the user from opening your web page twice then what do you plan to do about multiple tabs within one Chrome session. You will have to program your website to allow only one instance of user activity...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Chromium is not Chrome as far as i know. Actually Chrome is preinstalled and the only browser aviable in my scenario, so even if Chromium may be the opensource version of Chrome (and even if it was completly identical) is not the same thing for me, is not aviable and so i can not use it.

Comment: Ok, but how do you plan to prevent users from opening multiple tabs and visiting your site. I think you are trying to solve your problem in a very, very wrong way...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus as stated before tabs are not a problem, users are not there to make trouble. Desktop launcher avoid multiple tabs in the same windows, what i need now is a way to avoid multiple windows to be launched by desktop shortcut.
The page hasn't any login mechanism, so a server side logic to prevent this seems to be pure pain.

Comment: So you're having a user training issue. In Windows 7 you can pin a program to the taskbar and upon opening the program it will not let them open it twice.

Comment: So you propose to remove desktop shortcut and pin it to taskbar instead.
I've just tried and it seems to work as i need (doing so users need to right click and explicitly ask to have another istance and that can not be considered a mistake :) )
Thank

Comment: Correct, but they can also middle-click to start a new instance immediately.

Comment: Something here could be useful if you wanted to get fancy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script